# iOS 15 Beta keyWindow not available in viewDidLoad

Tags: viewdidload, uiapplication, ios15, keywindow

We have a lot of logs to Crashlytics where the `keyWindow` ist `nil` after app startup in `viewDidLoad` of the first `viewController` show on screen. Anyone else having problems to access `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController` on app startup with the current iOS 15 betas (19A5337a)?

As we are still supporting iOS 12 (will change after the iOS 15 release), we do not use the `UISceneDelegate` to hangle lifecycle events (`UIApplicationDelegate`
is used).

iOS 14 or below if working fine.

Any ideas or hints how to fix this? Maybe it is sill "early" beta and it will disappear when we can submit builds for iOS 15 with the GM version of Xcode...

Thank you :)